# Using Outfile print, program execution error

Tags: java, file-io, printing

This is my class which I am trying to get a number generated and if they number doesn't equal 1, it will loop until it does but count how many times it looped, and how ever many times it looped will be printed out to a file. It compiles fine it just gets stuck at executing when I try to run the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random; 
public class BottleCapPrizeV2
{
    public static void main (String [ ] args) throws IOException
    {
        int openedCaps = 0;
        int randNum = 0;
        PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new File("MonteCarlo.txt"));
        Random randNumList = new Random();

        for (int loop = 1; loop <= 1000; loop++)
        {
            randNum = randNumList.nextInt(5)+1;
            while (randNum != 1)
            {
                openedCaps++;
            }
            outFile.println(openedCaps);
        }
        outFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by it gets stuck ? Are you getting an exception or is the program going in a infinite loo . Please be a bit more clear

Comment: This is all it does - http://puu.sh/cuyAA/a781972bbe.jpg

Comment: Please enclose your code that uses PrintWriter in a try catch block and close the PrintWriter instance in the finally block.
It is good programming practice to do so . Do no rely on javas garbage collection mechanism to kick in.

Answer (score 0):

It gets stuck because nothing is changing the value of randNum inside the while loop. so it just keeps looping

```
while (randNum != 1)
{
    openedCaps++;
}
```

randNum is always != 1